# How to remove class if another doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently trying to display a hidden button which only displays when a link is clicked, but i'm unsure on how to display it if the link doesn't exist.

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
    $('.wp-block-file.aligncenter a').click(function(e)
    {
      $('.learndash_mark_complete_button').removeClass('hidden');
    });

  });
})(jQuery);
```

```
<div class="wp-block-file aligncenter"><a href=".pdf" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener" class="customize-unpreviewable">Open PDF</a></div>

<input type="submit" value="Mark Complete" class="learndash_mark_complete_button hidden">
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like? You could potentially use the sibling CSS selector to hide the button where preceded by the link. Thus, if the link doesn't exist, the button wouldn't be hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the *length* of the link element to add the class to the element:

```
if(!$('.wp-block-file.aligncenter a').length){
  $('.learndash_mark_complete_button').removeClass('hidden');
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
if(!$('.wp-block-file.aligncenter a').length){
  $('.learndash_mark_complete_button').removeClass('hidden');
}
```

```css
.hidden{
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="submit" value="Mark Complete" class="learndash_mark_complete_button hidden">
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you for the help, much appreciated by a huge JS noobie! :-)

Comment: @addisonwtaylor, you are most welcome, glad to help:)